# How to Add a Dropdown to this specific Nav?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

Since im pretty new and just started my first website i am only started to learning but even though i can't java i want atleast a simple Dropdown menu which i adjust in looks.

My Code for the Nav is:

```
<nav>   
                    <a class="nav1home" href="index.html"></a>
                    <a class="nav2" href="referenzen.html"></a>
                    <a class="nav3" href="kontakt.html"></a>
                    <a class="nav4" href="marcel.html"></a>
            </nav>



    .nav1 {
    width:60px;
    height:25px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-image:url(../img/home.jpeg);

}
.nav1:hover {
    width:60px;
    height:25px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-image:url(../img/home_hover.jpg);

}

.nav1home {
    width:60px;
    height:25px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-image:url(../img/home_hover.jpg);

}
.nav1home:hover {
    width:60px;
    height:25px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-image:url(../img/home.jpeg);

}

.nav2 {
    width:119px;
    height:25px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-image:url(../img/referenzen.jpeg);

}
.nav2:hover {
    width:119px;
    height:25px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-image:url(../img/referenzen_hover.jpg);

}

.nav3 {
    width:79px;
    height:21px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-image:url(../img/kontakt.jpg);

}
.nav3:hover {
    width:79px;
    height:21px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-image:url(../img/kontakt_hover.jpg);

}

.nav4 {
    width:73px;
    height:21px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-image:url(../img/marcel.jpg);

}
.nav4:hover {
    width:73px;
    height:21px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-image:url(../img/marcel_hover.jpg);

}
nav > a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#1f1f1f;

}
```

I want to add now a little Dropdown menu which i can "adjust" to the looks of the webpage, but even googling that just makes me more confused.
So any tips how to do that?

Comment: don't talk about java when you mean javascript. They are different languages. As for dropdown menu, do you mean a html select element or something else?

Comment: oh god i'm so sorry of course i meant Javascript.

I don't really know which methods are used and which would fit my Nav the best. but i mean something like you hover the nav point "referenzen" and then a little slider came out where you got all the different sites which refers to "referenzen"

Like you'd hover over a movie Site over "genre" and then comes all the different genres slided out

Comment: ah ok... you mean something like this: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp